# gnuplot how to create an output that does not have a chart

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to create a GNUplot without the chart?

I am wondering if I can use GNUplot to create a form that displays text.
This is so that I can have GNUplot create my document as a .png file.

My thinking is to use labels placed on the form to create my document then plot it to a .png file.
This will allow me to view this in my Qt QGraphicsView.

Example would look something like this:

```
{CustomerName}: Yield & Cpk 
 Version: {Version}
 Date & Time Range:   Start: '10/01/2014 00:00:00'   End: '10/31/2014 23:59:59'

 Total Tested = 3899 
 Total Passed = 3829 
 Total Failed = 70 
 -------------------------
 Yield = 98.20 


 Cpk: **********************************************************************************************************
Test                       Limits             Avg       STD     L Cpk   U Cpk   Less than 1.33
CURRENT_              15.000 << 40.000        27.709    0.303   13.998  13.538  
FREQ_PILOT_FREQ     7497.000 << 7503.000    7500.775    0.040   31.110  18.332  
FREQ_PILOT_LEVEL     -15.000 << -13.000      -13.907    0.104    3.493   2.901
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean with 'form' and 'chart' in this context. To save plots a png use e.g. `set terminal pngcairo; set output 'test.png'; plot x`.

Comment: If you just want to create a form in .png format, it may be easier to create it in a regular word processor then take a screenshot, or save as pdf and convert the pdf to png.

Comment: I am creating this from C++ Qt program.  I need this to be in a .png or other type of image file to show it int the QGraphicsView.

Comment: This is not a task for gnuplot.

Comment: @Kevin I would be very disappointed of Qt if there isn't in it at least a dozen  methods to draw text on some sort of graphics canvas